# Migrate project to Gradle 8.0 - Error Task

Tags: android, gradle

I'm migrating my multi module project to Gradle 8.0. After carefully updating the Gradle files it gives the following error.

```
Could not create task :app:transformClassesWithAPMSPluginFor [Variant]
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem is due to huawei dependencies.Huawei's libraries currently do not support gradle 8.0.